# Burn bootloader to Arduino Uno using ARM-USB-OCD

Tags: arduino-uno, bootloader, programmer

I have ARM-USB-OCD created by OLIMEX. I am interested in can I use this to burn a bootloader to Arduino Uno. As I know Atmega 328P can be programmed using JTAG protocol which has also ARM-USB-ODC, so if it really can anyone give the circuit or something like this.
Here is my device [(ARM-USB-ODC) manual](https://www.olimex.com/Products/ARM/JTAG/_resources/ARM-USB-OCD_and_OCD_H_manual.pdf).

Comment: Where did you get that information the `Atmega328` supports JTAG? There is only the `DebugWire` interface. And as far as I remember, the `AVR JTAG` might be kinda incompatible with anything else. However the programmer is FTDI based, so it might be possible to use it as clasic serial programmer.

Comment: Atmega328P does not have JTAG pins.

Answer (score 1):

*Probably, but likely not easily*

To program an AVR chip you likely want to use the AVR ISP protocol, which is not JTAG, but like JTAG is a synchronous serial protocol with a clock, a data line in each direction, and one additional control pin compared to the several mode/status pins of JTAG.

According to your link, the `ARM-USB-OCD` is based on an FT2232C USB interface chip.

`avrdude` documentation indicates that this is an interface it knows how to use, though it will likely take some study to figure out how.

The final question would be wiring - you'll need to figure out which JTAG-style signal names map to which FTDI functional pins, and how those should best be connected to AVR ISP pins in a way which avrdude can use.  Additionally, you'd have to make sure that any buffering between the FTDI chip and the pins is compatible with your needs, both in terms of data direction and voltage level.

Note that you can easily use any ATmega328-based Arduino as an ISP programmer for a same-voltage target - not really production worthy, but if you just need to move your project along *today* it's a handy option.